Maps in Dafny: what's wrong here?
I have defined a function and checked it:
function removeInMap(w: string, m: map<string, int>): map<string, int>
{
    map x: string | x in m  && x != w :: m[x]
}

method checkRemoveInMap() 
{
    var m: map<string, int>:= map["aa":= 0, "ab" := 1];
    var newM1:= removeInMap("aa", m);
    assert |m.Keys| == 2;
    assert m["aa"] == 0;
    assert "ab" in newM1;
    assert newM1["ab"] == 1;
    assert !("aa" in newM1);
    var newM2:=  removeInMap("bb", newM1);
    assert "ab" in newM2;
    assert !("aa" in newM2);
    assert newM1 == newM2;
 }

Now I try to generalize my function in this way:
function closureRemoveInMap(s: seq<string>, m: map<string, int>): map<string, int>
{
   if |s| == 0 then m else closureRemoveInMap(s[1..], removeInMap(s[0], m))
}

But when I check it, something is wrong because Dafny does not prove the last three asserts.
method checkClosureRemoveInMaps() 
{
    var m: map<string, int>:= map["aa":= 0, "ab" := 1];
    var newM:= closureRemoveInMap(["aa", "bb"], m);
    assert |m.Keys| == 2;
    assert m["aa"] == 0;
    assert "ab" in newM;
    assert newM["ab"] == 1;
    assert !("aa" in newM); 
}


In absence of postconditions, Dafny unrolls definition of function up to certain amount to prove required facts.
That unrolling might not be enough to prove asserted facts. That is the case here. You can control amount of unrolling using :fuel attribute.
Increasing fuel to 2 here is enough to prove facts in checkClosureRemoveInMaps
function {:fuel 2} closureRemoveInMap(s: seq<string>, m: map<string, int>): (r: map<string, int>)
{
   if |s| == 0 then m else 
     closureRemoveInMap(s[1..], removeInMap(s[0], m))
}

It is better to add postconditions to functions so that it can reason about symbolic values instead of just concrete values like ["aa", "bb"] at call site like this
function removeInMap(w: string, m: map<string, int>): (r: map<string, int>)
  ensures w !in r
  ensures forall k :: k in m && k != w ==> k in r && m[k] == r[k]
  ensures forall k :: k in r ==> k in m && r[k] == m[k]
{
    map x: string | x in m  && x != w :: m[x]
}

function closureRemoveInMap(s: seq<string>, m: map<string, int>): (r: map<string, int>)
  ensures forall k :: k in s ==> k !in r
  ensures forall k :: k in m && k !in s ==> k in r && m[k] == r[k]
  ensures forall k :: k in r ==> k in m && r[k] == m[k]
{
   if |s| == 0 then m else 
     closureRemoveInMap(s[1..], removeInMap(s[0], m))
}

